# Get Distinct elements in two mysql tables with selected field values using PHP or SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Assuming there are two tables in SQL that have nearly identical values among which the first table could be considered as the complete data and second table has the selective data. I need to get the data in the first table that is not the part of second table. but here I need to compare selective rows from both the tables.eg assuming there are two tables as

```
total_students (s_id, s_name, s_class) 
failed_students (s_id, s_name, s_class)
```

All I need to get is the list of students who are in the table student but not in the failed_student only for a specific class.

I tried using the `array_diff()` on the results for parameterised select queries from both the tables but couldn't as the result is in object form. Moreover for such logic I shall have to fire multiple queries.

Also tried resolving the same with sql as suggested [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/how-to-do-an-inverse-join/3224) using the following query

```
SELECT * 
FROM total_students 
LEFT OUTER JOIN failed_students ON total_students.s_id = failed_students.s_id 
WHERE total_students.s_id IS NULL 
  AND total_students.s_class = "fourth";
```

but this also does not helps.

Kindly suggest a way to implement it efficiently using PHP or SQL (preferred).

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle MINUS takes 2 data sets and gives you the difference.

```
SELECT s_id,s_name,s_class FROM total_students where total_students.s_class="fourth"
MINUS
SELECT s_id,s_name,s_class FROM failed_students where failed_students.s_class="fourth"
```

And another way.  You want to check if the failed_students ID is null (assuming that's a key)

```
SELECT * 
FROM total_students 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN failed_students 
      ON total_students.s_id = failed_students.s_id 
WHERE failed_students.s_id IS NULL AND total_students.s_class="fourth";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just came across a simpler solution as

```
select * from total_students where class="fourth" and s_id not in (select s_id from failed_students where class="fourth");
```

This seemed to work for me but not sure that this is efficient in all situations.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the total_students not in the failed_students, so your `WHERE` condition should be on the `failed_students` table, not on the total_students:

```
SELECT * 
FROM total_students 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN failed_students 
      ON total_students.s_id = failed_students.s_id 

WHERE failed_students.s_id IS NULL
  AND total_students.s_class = 'fourth';
```